# Absolute Positioned DIVs are not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two DIVs (previous-image and next-image) that are absolutely positioned. Here is my structure:

```
<div id="sheet" onclick="close()">
    <div id="popover">
        <div id="previous-image" onclick="previous()">&laquo;</div>
        <img src="http://cynthiawoodyardlandscapedesign.com/watermark.php?src=images/main1.jpg&x=0&y=470&opacity=50" id="popover-image" />
        <div id="next-image" onclick="next()">&raquo;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Link: http://cynthiawoodyardlandscapedesign.com/

Here is my CSS:

```
#next-image {
    position: absolute;
    right: -100px;
    top: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 50px;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
    -moz-text-stroke: 1px black;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    z-index: 200;
    background: transparent;
    color: white;
}
#previous-image {
    position: absolute;
    left: -100px;
    top: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    z-index: 200;
    font-size: 50px;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
    -moz-text-stroke: 1px black;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: transparent;
    color: white;
}
```

My JavaScript:

```
$("#sheet").click(function() {
    $("#sheet").animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 200, function() {
        $("#sheet").hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

Seems you had omitted the actual HTML of your `#sheet` element, which has a `display: none` set on the element, and therefore all is invisible inside the sheet element, including the arrows.

Your actual HTML on your site is:

```
<div id="sheet" onclick="close()" style="display: none;">
    <div id="popover" onclick="close()">
        <div id="previous-image" onclick="previous()">«</div>
        <img src="watermark.php?src=images/main1.jpg&amp;x=0&amp;y=420&amp;opactity=50"
        id="popover-image" onclick="close()">
        <div id="next-image" onclick="next()">»</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Removing that `style="display: none;"` will show the arrows again.

Comment: Agreed. Here's a fiddle with the left and right set to 0px. http://jsfiddle.net/7aVDN/

Comment: Weird. I hadn't noticed because they were working fine until I set: `#sheet { display: table;} #popover { display: table-cell; }` It was confusing.

Comment: @afterimagedesign: Sorry there was no CSS for the sheet in the question. Is there anything in there that would impact the visibility?

Comment: It was because the `#popover` had a width of 800px but when it is table-cell it has a width of 100%, and the arrows are in the `#popover`.  It is `display: table;`, not none.

Comment: @afterimagedesign: I saw the style on the site now and yes, the off-set is fine as it was inside an inner-container of the page. So the off-set of `-100px` is fine after all. It is your `display: none` style on the `#sheet` element which is there when you insepct your site's styles on the `#sheet` element. I added that info now as well to the answer.

Comment: @afterimagedesign: `and the arrows are in the #popover. It is display: table;, not none.` However, the element surrounding `#popover` is the `#sheet` element which has `display: none` therefore all elements inside it are hidden regardless of their independent style.

Comment: Ohh because I use jQuery `.hide()` on the DOM ready because the `#sheet` is an overlay that makes the site inaccessable until you exit the sheet.